# How to use a JavaScript value inside EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How can I use a `JavaScript` value inside an `EJS` statement?

E.g. I grab the value of a select option with `JavaScript` and want to load data from an object depending on the value.

```
var gerichtSelectID = $("#gericht" + id).val(); //e.g. 8
var gerichtPreisID = <%= gerichte.data[gerichtSelectID].preis_id %>; // should be gerichte.data[8].preis_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS values can't be modified in JavaScript, but the easiest solution is to convert the EJS object into JSON.

```
var gerichte = <%- JSON.stringify(gerichte) %>;
var gerichtSelectID = $("#gericht" + id).val();
var gerichtPreisID = gerichte.data[gerichtSelectID].preis_id;
```